# Enable default TTS engine from program in android

Tags: android

Is it possible check if the default Text-to-Speech engine is enabled in Android? If not, can I enable it through my Android program? If so, how?

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

The above code shows different TTS available and shows as a dialog box and then I choose the required TTS and click OK. Once I do that - the system (tablet or phone) automatically chooses the chosen TTS and enables it.

Can I do the same by putting it in customized layout (list out the TTS installed) and can I choose what is required and enable it by click enable button or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can list available TTS engines in ICS and you can test availability by package name and language on Froyo and later. TTS engines are controlled by the system, so you cannot disable/enable them from your app. You can only prompt the user to do so.

Re: edited question. This is a completely different story. This intent checks whether the TTS data is installed, and if you have multiple engines you will have to choose one to handle the intent. This is just the way Android dispatches intents and has nothing to do with TTS. If you make the intent explicit by calling `Intent.setPackage("my.tts.package")` the dialog won't be shown. Note that this does not check whether a TTS engine is enabled. I haven't checked but I doubt that if the TTS engine is disabled in Settings this will enable it.

Comment: Thanks - what do you mean by prompt?

Comment: Show a dialog saying 'Please enable TTS engine XXX to use feature YYY' and maybe take them to the settings screen if they press OK.

Comment: Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE); 

Prompts different TTS Engines. I end up choosing what ever is good for me and click OK. The system chooses the chosen TTS automatically after that..  can I do this in customized layout - Like in my style rather on default option?

Comment: Editted the question in the top for better understanding

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. You mean to say if you say Intent.setPackage("my.tts.package") - this will automatically choose the required package and then use it. if that is the case - I am fine with it. After looking into Jellybean, Andriod 2.2, Android 4.0.3 - all of them have the TTS enabled by default. Please correct me if I am wrong?